# Promise not resolving - Mocha + CasperJS + Q

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, casperjs, q

I'm trying to use the Q promise library in my mocha-casperjs tests. I'm wondering if anyone could help me understand why the code below won't resolve? The code is written in coffeescript and launched using mocha-casperjs

```
Q = require('./q')
casper.errorHandler = ->
    @echo @ 
    throw new CasperError 'Promise Failed'

## Promise version of casper.open()
casper._open = (url) ->
    deferred = Q.defer()
    @open url, deferred.resolve
    return deferred.promise

describe 'Main Test', ->
    before ->
        casper.start()
        console.log 'casper started'
    it 'Test Case 1', (done) ->
        casper._open('http://google.com')
        .then ( ->
            'Google'.should.matchTitle
            done()), casper.errorHandler()
```

When the error handler's called, casper echoes [object Casper], currently at about:blank which means the page hasn't loaded yet. But I thought the promise function would wait for that before moving onto the .then()?

Comment: I don't know about mocha, but if you're using standard CasperJS, you need to call casper.run() to actually start the execution.

Comment: Yea should've mentioned it but mocha-casper handles that part.

Comment: Don't use `done` mocha supports promises already.

Comment: Their website says that but I'm confused in how to use it. Does it have a built in promise support that I don't need to use Q?